AppBar's IconButtons overflowed by X pixels
I am new to flutter and I am trying to understand the logic behind this problem.
Let's start by showing part of my code first. (I run the app on windows desktop as a device)
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            widget.title,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          shape: const Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            const IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(Icons.developer_mode,),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5,), //1
            const IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(Icons.handshake_rounded,),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5,), //2
            const IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag,),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5,), //3
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.person_rounded,),
              onPressed: null,
            const SizedBox(width: 5,), //4
          ],
        ),
        body: //... the body is empty btw
        ),
      ),
    );
    }

Just from this I get as a result the image below:
enter image description here
And here everything is ok, If I remove the 4 SizedBox it works good like before but if I increase the width of the SizedBox from 5 to 10 for example and I resize the app using my mouse, I get this:
enter image description here
Why is this happening? It works when the width of the 4 SizedBox is 5 but not when is higher.
I tried to put them in a Row and after I wrapped each IconButton in a Expanded or in a Flexible or inside a FittedBox with fit: BoxFit.scaleDown but I get always the same error, with Expanded and Flexible the app fizzes.
This is the error given by the debug:
Exception caught by rendering library
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by X pixels on the right.


The relevant error-causing widget was:AppBar

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

I put the most important part, I hope, it's very long.
Thanks in advance!
